# Is it possible to create subwikis with MediaWiki?

Tags: php, wiki, mediawiki

I wan't to create a Wiki for our company which has several product requiring their own Wiki. Is it possible to create subwikis with MediaWiki? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible within MediaWiki. The closest you would get is using custom namespaces (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces).

Commercial enterprise products like Confluence do offer this functionality.

If you want to keep it free you could create multiple MediaWiki instances. MediaWiki setup is not terribly complex and can easily be scripted to set up multiple instances using multiple databases and Apache VirtualHosts.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami creates an easy to use mediawiki stack for separate wikis: https://bitnami.com/stack/mediawiki

I have created a virtualbox and added the bitnami virtual machine to the virtualbox.

Here is the information about my virtual box:

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-103-generic x86_64)

```
         ___ _ _                   _
        | _ |_) |_ _ _  __ _ _ __ (_)
        | _ \ |  _| ' \/ _` | '  \| |
        |___/_|\__|_|_|\__,_|_|_|_|_|
```

*** Welcome to the Bitnami MediaWiki 1.28.0-0** 
   **Documentation:  https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/mediawiki/ ***

Last login: Tue Jun 20 13:57:34 2017

Comment: If you can provide some information not just a link